# How to fix rails 4 hyperlinks?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to display someone's profile links to their social media profiles. My current code is

```
<p>
<strong>Linkedin:</strong>
<%= link_to @person.linkedin, @person.linkedin %>
</p>
```

It works and the link does load, but it goes to localhost:3000/user/linkedin.com/in/user instead of linkedin.com/in/username

Thanks!

Comment: What's the value of `linkedin`? A url or a linkedin username?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add make sure the linkedin hyperlinks have a protocol (http, https, etc).

Any link without a protocol is assumed to be a relative path, which is why the hyperlinks are getting appended to your website url.

A solution would be to manually add a "http://" string at the beginning of every person's linkedin hyperlink in your database. Your code should work fine after that.

**Edit:** Or you can change it on the fly like so (the other answers won't work since it looks like `@person.linkedin` contains the entire hyperlink not just the linkedin user)

```
<%= link_to @person.linkedin, "https://#{@person.linkedin}" %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Rails link helpers follow the format:

```
link_to(name = nil, options = nil, html_options = nil, &block)
```

The second @person.linkedin path is a local path as determined by your routes file in your config folder.  If the link you need follows a certain format you can do something like

```
<%= link_to "LinkTextHere", "http://www.linkedin.com/#{@person}/profile" %>
```

I can answer in more detail if you give me the exact outcome you need as well as what you want from the .linkedin value.  Also, typing "rake routes" in your console will show all paths you currently have and can help troubleshoot issues like why @person.linkedin is routing locally.